# Generate PDF with jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

I use jsPDF to generate PDF but somehow, the margin that I've set on it seems not working for pagesplit.

I tried this method but not working as well (when it comes to second page, the margin is not working): [Jspdf addHTML pagesplit option is stretching the pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736662/jspdf-addhtml-pagesplit-option-is-stretching-the-pages)

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 2.25;

pdf.addHTML(document.querySelector('#print'), 0, 0, { 
    pagesplit: true,
    margin: {
        top: 50,
        right: 25,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 25,
        useFor: 'page' 
   }
},function () {
    pdf.save('print.pdf');
});
```

***tried this method too**:

```
pdf.addHTML(document.querySelector('#print'), 25, 50, { 
    pagesplit: true,
    margin: {
        top: 50,
        right: 25,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 25,
        useFor: 'page' 
   }
},function () {
    pdf.save('print.pdf');
});
```

Below is the result:
[image]

Comment: what version are you using? the versions can be very different.

Comment: May I know which version can be used for this option?

Comment: I don't know about that. I have `pageBreak: "avoid"` where you have `pagesplit: true`, but that could just be that i'm using the [jspdf-autotable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) plugin